# IDurableOrchestrationContext.SetCustomStatus does not update status immediately

Tags: azure-functions

The goal is to update the custom status of the orchestrator using IDurableOrchestrationContext.SetCustomStatus call.
The code example is below, but the point is set custom status right on its start ("Checking"). Check if there are any "Running" already or "Checking" instances.

In the example below I set the custom status and check it right away (in future orchestator will be paused if there are instances running and check again later, waiting for its turn)
**The problem is**: if I check the status (with .ListInstancesAsync() API) right after I set it - there are no instances returned with my custom status...
If I put some activity in between the calls (setting status and getting it) I am able to get the right instance.

**It seems that IDurableOrchestrationContext.SetCustomStatus call needs some time to actually set the custom status in Azure storage table... What is the recommended way to set/get the custom status here?**

```
public static class Class1
{
    [FunctionName(nameof(TriggerAsync))]
    public static async Task TriggerAsync(
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient orchestrationClient,
        //[TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo timer,
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        logger.LogWarning("Trigger. Starting new orchestration");
        var id = await orchestrationClient.StartNewAsync(nameof(OrchestrationAsync));
        logger.LogWarning("Trigger. Started new orchestration");
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(OrchestrationAsync))]
    public static async Task OrchestrationAsync(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(log);

        try
        {
            context.SetCustomStatus("Superb");

            logger.LogWarning($"Orchestration. GetInstances Start");
            var instances = await context.CallActivityAsync<int>("GetInstances", null);
            logger.LogWarning($"Orchestration. GetInstances result: {instances}");
            logger.LogWarning($"Orchestration. GetInstances End");

            logger.LogWarning($"Orchestration. Activity1 Start");
            await context.CallActivityAsync("Activity1", null);
            logger.LogWarning($"Orchestration. Activity1 End");
        }
        catch
        {
            logger.LogWarning($"Orchestration. Error");
            throw;
        }

        logger.LogWarning($"Orchestration. Done");
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(Activity1))]
    public static async Task Activity1(
        [ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var rndNum = rnd.Next(60);

        logger.LogWarning($"Activity. Doing some work with {rndNum} seconds duration");
        await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, rndNum));
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(GetInstances))]
    public static async Task<int> GetInstances(
        [ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext context,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger logger)
    {
        var statuses = new List<OrchestrationRuntimeStatus>
        {
            OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Running,
            OrchestrationRuntimeStatus.Pending
        };

        var condition = new OrchestrationStatusQueryCondition
        {
            RuntimeStatus = statuses
        };

        var response = await starter.ListInstancesAsync(condition, CancellationToken.None);
        return response.DurableOrchestrationState.Count(x => x.CustomStatus.ToString() == "Superb");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your orchestrator seems to be violating at least one of the rules for them, it shouldn't be blocking on async tasks. Most likely the framework sets the status the next time execution is returned from the function (await/return). What are you trying to achieve ultimately?

Comment: @juunas, just update my example. Triggered by httpTrigger, additionally I wrapped GetInstances call into an activity and now using await, so it's not blocking anything. However the result is the same - GetInstances activity returns no instances with custom state, but the state was set before the GetInstances call...

Comment: Yeah it looks a lot more correct now, will have to take a look at the DF source code to see what it actually does with that custom status internally. If I recall that function itself just serializes the input you give it and sets in on some field.

Comment: @juunas, Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @juunas, would it be helpful if I ask the same directly in QA on github here? - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/discussions